# list item positioning

Tags: css, list, positioning, html-lists

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>My Videos</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + 
        (autoplay?1:0)+'&version=3', 'player', '585', '355', '9.0.0', false, 
        false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
        /*Parse the facebook like button*/
        $('#like').html('<fb:like href="'+playerUrl+'" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="65" action="like" font="segoe ui" colorscheme="light" />')
        if (typeof FB  != "undefined"){
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('like'))
        }
}
function showMyVideos(data) {
    var feed = data.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 20);
        var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
        var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
        var videoId = playerUrl.substr(playerUrl.indexOf('v/')+2, 11);          
        playerUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoId;  
        html.push('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'', playerUrl, '\', true)">',
                  '<img src="', 
                  thumbnailUrl, '" width="94" height="58"/> </span>', title, '</li>');
    }
    html.push('</ul>');
    document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML = html.join('');
    if (entries.length > 0) {
        loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
    }
}
$(function(){
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed_Autos?time=today&alt=json-in-script&max-results=5&format=5",
            cache: false,
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success: function(data){
                showMyVideos(data);
          },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                alert("Not able to fetch the data due to feed unavailability!!!");
            }
        });
})
</script>

<style>
body {
background:#fff;
color:silver;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:100%;
line-height:1.125em;
}

#videoContainer {
font-size:.75em;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:5px;
}

#like {
height:15px;
margin-top:10px;
text-align:right;
}

object {
-moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #ccc;
box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #ccc;
}

ul.videos {
list-style:none;
margin-bottom:1em;
margin-left:0;
padding-left:0;
}

ul.videos li {
cursor:pointer;
display:inline;
margin-bottom:1em;
padding-right:28px;
color:blue;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="videoContainer">
    <div id="playerContainer">
        <div id="player">
        </div>
        <div id="like">
        </div>
        <div id="videos">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me how to position the title of the small thumbnails.

Thank's

Comment: That doesn't matter. It seems I can't move them around with padding and margin. I just want to have css acces to them. I'm not even sure what they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a closing span tag in your output, but no starting span tag.

Comment: Hi @msjolund That seems to work(thank you) but now the first thumbnail is not cooperating. Could you please tell me if there is something special about the first thumbnail-title.

Comment: Never mind, it was the css. (And why the hell are people voting this down??)